# Correct algorithm to resize a rectangle on mouse drag

Tags: canvas, geometry, paperjs

I am using paper.js to make a level editor. I am currently bugging on how to resize a rectangle properly

Currently, I am doing something like :

```
 rect.onMouseDrag = event => {
    let selectedNode = rect.selectedNode;
      selectedNode.point.x += event.delta.x;
      selectedNode.point.y += event.delta.y;
      switch (rect.selectedNode.index) {
        case 0:
          rect.segments[1].point.x += event.delta.x;
          rect.segments[3].point.y += event.delta.y;
          break;
        case 1:
          rect.segments[0].point.x += event.delta.x;
          rect.segments[2].point.y += event.delta.y;
          break;
        case 2:
          rect.segments[3].point.x += event.delta.x;
          rect.segments[1].point.y += event.delta.y;
          break;
        case 3:
          rect.segments[selectedNode.index - 1].point.x += event.delta.x;
          rect.segments[selectedNode.index - 3].point.y += event.delta.y;
          break;
  };
```

So I just check the adjacent points and move them accordingly to the mouse event.
It works fine for AABB's

[image]

But as soon as the rectangle is rotated, everything breaks
[image]

Can anyone explain or just link me what's the correct algorithm to resize a rectangle and keep it rectangle ? I think this question has already been adressed but I can't find anything useful.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, my good friend of the compote zrugvanoudu35 speedrunned this problem:

```
     switch (rect.selectedNode.index) {
        case 0:
          rect.segments[1].point.x +=
            event.delta.x * Math.cos(rad) * Math.cos(rad) +
            event.delta.y * Math.cos(rad) * Math.sin(rad);
          rect.segments[1].point.y +=
            event.delta.x * Math.sin(rad) * Math.cos(rad) +
            event.delta.y * Math.sin(rad) * Math.sin(rad);
          rect.segments[3].point.x +=
            event.delta.x * Math.sin(rad) * Math.sin(rad) +
            -event.delta.y * Math.sin(rad) * Math.cos(rad);
          rect.segments[3].point.y +=
            -event.delta.x * Math.sin(rad) * Math.cos(rad) +
            event.delta.y * Math.cos(rad) * Math.cos(rad);
          break;
        case 1:
          rect.segments[0].point.x +=
            event.delta.x * Math.cos(rad) * Math.cos(rad) +
            event.delta.y * Math.cos(rad) * Math.sin(rad);
          rect.segments[0].point.y +=
            event.delta.x * Math.sin(rad) * Math.cos(rad) +
            event.delta.y * Math.sin(rad) * Math.sin(rad);
          rect.segments[2].point.x +=
            event.delta.x * Math.sin(rad) * Math.sin(rad) +
            -event.delta.y * Math.sin(rad) * Math.cos(rad);
          rect.segments[2].point.y +=
            -event.delta.x * Math.sin(rad) * Math.cos(rad) +
            event.delta.y * Math.cos(rad) * Math.cos(rad);
          break;
        case 2:
          rect.segments[3].point.x +=
            event.delta.x * Math.cos(rad) * Math.cos(rad) +
            event.delta.y * Math.cos(rad) * Math.sin(rad);
          rect.segments[3].point.y +=
            event.delta.x * Math.sin(rad) * Math.cos(rad) +
            event.delta.y * Math.sin(rad) * Math.sin(rad);
          rect.segments[1].point.x +=
            event.delta.x * Math.sin(rad) * Math.sin(rad) +
            -event.delta.y * Math.sin(rad) * Math.cos(rad);
          rect.segments[1].point.y +=
            -event.delta.x * Math.sin(rad) * Math.cos(rad) +
            event.delta.y * Math.cos(rad) * Math.cos(rad);
          break;
        case 3:
          rect.segments[2].point.x +=
            event.delta.x * Math.cos(rad) * Math.cos(rad) +
            event.delta.y * Math.cos(rad) * Math.sin(rad);
          rect.segments[2].point.y +=
            event.delta.x * Math.sin(rad) * Math.cos(rad) +
            event.delta.y * Math.sin(rad) * Math.sin(rad);
          rect.segments[0].point.x +=
            event.delta.x * Math.sin(rad) * Math.sin(rad) +
            -event.delta.y * Math.sin(rad) * Math.cos(rad);
          rect.segments[0].point.y +=
            -event.delta.x * Math.sin(rad) * Math.cos(rad) +
            event.delta.y * Math.cos(rad) * Math.cos(rad);
          break;
      }
```

He's a man of wise.

[image: 2D rectangle resizing algorithm]

Obviously this needs some refactoring but it's easier to post the comprehensive answer this way.

Answer (score 0):

Make projection of mouse move vector onto rectangle side vectors (they depends on rotation angle) and apply corresponding changes to rectangle side lengths.

One rectangle side has unit direction vector `(cos(fi), sin(fi))`, another (neighbor) side - `(-sin(fi), cos(fi))` and for mouse shift `(mx, my)` applied to vertex between these sides:

```
delta_width = mx * cos(fi) + my * sin(fi)
delta_height = -mx * sin(fi) + my * cos(fi)
```

Note that signs depend on which vertex is moved

Comment: Ok this goes a bit fast for me. I'll try to somehow test this but it's not easy since I have to compute most of your starting variables. I did find something that might help me for this : http://paperjs.org/tutorials/geometry/vector-geometry/
But keep in mind that i can only set the "point" values and not directly interact with rectnagle side width / length (from what I know)
If you have a more step by step explanation, I'll take it :)

Comment: But I don't know how your **rotated** rectangle is defined, so gave an general outline of solution.